# ip forward not work? can't ping from a subnet to b subnet in same TAP interface

Tags: networking, routing, bridge

**Hi all, I am new to linux networking, had a question about routing lan to lan with a TAP interface.**

My **Topology**:

```
          L2tp_Server
       [tap_lan2lan_lab]
       169.6.211.254/24
              |
              |
    ----------------------
    |                    |
    |                    |
169.6.211.10/32       169.6.211.20/32
[l2tp_out]            [l2tp_out]
RouterA               RouterB
[eth3]                [eth3]
192.168.100.1/24      192.168.200.1/24
    |                    |
    |                    |
192.168.100.100/24    192.168.200.200/24
   PcA                  PcB
```

On **L2tp_Server**, i added the route in TAP interface:

```
ip route add 192.168.100.0/24 via 169.6.211.10 dev tap_lan2lan_lab src 169.6.211.254
ip route add 192.168.200.0/24 via 169.6.211.20 dev tap_lan2lan_lab src 169.6.211.254
```

**sysctl** on **L2tp_Server**:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

**iptables** on **L2tp_Server**:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

route on **RouterA**:

```
169.2.211.0/24 dev l2tp_out
192.168.200.0/24 dev l2tp_out
```

route on **RouterB**:

```
169.6.211.0/24 l2tp_out
192.168.100.0/24 l2tp_out
```

### **Now the Trouble is:**

On **subnet** 169.6.211.0/24 is all connected and can ping to each other.
But **subnet** 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.200.0/24 can't ping to each other.

**What problem in my topology? Maybe the topology is false?**

Comment: I don't know what you're using to operate the tap device, but with openvpn the routing between connected clients can be handled by openvpn itself, so the kernel routing tables isn't involved in that case. You might be in the same situation. Try e.g.tcpdump on the tap device to see if you can see the pings from one client net to the other.

Comment: Is forwarding on RouterA and RouterB enabled? After all, it's those routers that have to forward packets between `eth3` and `l2tp_out`. On L2tp_Server, where you enabled forwarding, you've shown only one interface, so this forwarding is not relevant for your topology.  Do PcA and PcB have correct routes/default routes (via 192.168.100.1 resp. 192.168.200.1)? If it still doesn't work, do a continous  `ping` from PcA to PcB, and test with `tcpdump` on each interface in order if you see packets.

Comment: One more thing that caught my eye: the addresses on RouterA and RouterB  should be `169.6.211.10/24` and `169.6.211.20/24`, not `/32`.

Comment: @wurtel Thanks for the reply, i think that's why my network is not work, i used a vpn software in server, and i created a tap interface to bridge the vpn user to each other vpn user in the interface. so if the routing is handled by software, that can explain my network problem, great thanks.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the suggesting, i'll try it.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Thanks for the reply, i used vpn software to connect user, it assign an ip with /32 submask by automatically.